# View python dict structures as dictionaries at pycharm

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

I am trying to check the content of a python dict at the variable explorer in the same way as a dataframe. Is there any way to view a python dict as dictionary in a pop-up window?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is missing in PyCharm unfortunately, but it is possible to convert your object to a Pandas DataFrame and view it in a popup:

```
import pandas as pd
my_obj = [{'abc':1,'def':2},{'abc':2,'def':3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_obj)
```

And then click "view as DataFrame" in PyCharm's variable view.